# Dropdown lists & conditional formatting in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I am making my business spreadsheet and my business is selling in multiple countries. So, for example, I have a drop-down list (and when Country is chosen I want it to affect the rest of the spreadsheet). In that list, I have all the countries I sell to. What I want to do is for example when I select UK it will update all the prices and costs that are there to GBP AND also hide specific columns that are not necessary for the UK. The same goes for other countries if US is selected I want to see $ currency and hide the column of VAT tax since it doesn't apply to the US.

To summarize, when Country is selected from the dropdown I want it to show different values and hide 1-2 columns. Wondering if this is even possible in sheets. Hopefully, this makes a little bit of sense. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes It is possible, get only the columns you want from a range.

### Dropdown from a list

> Go to Data > [Data validation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/186103?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop) Criteria: List from range and Enter a range or formula.

[image]

### The Formula

> Paste this formula next to srearch key range and below the column names you want to search, Take a look at this *"freshly made"* [**Example Sheet.**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oD0E6C-j4ZkSOrEFsxdffHjzZBh6-va2_61E3ddflM0/edit?usp=sharing)

```
=ArrayFormula(IF($B$2:$B="",,VLOOKUP($B$2:$B,$G$3:$J$16,MATCH(C$1,$G$2:$J$2,0),1)))
```

[image]

Choose the country and all the data will be populated, replacate this formula column and expand the lookup range to get more info put in place.

- we are using [`MATCH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en) to return the matching index from the column above for example Currency `C1` from the range `G2:J2` which is `2` in this case [`MATCH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en) function returns the matching value index "column" `2`, to be used as an index for [`vlookup`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en) function.

Comment: Wow, that looks easier than I thought! Thank you for the help and the formula:)